# Parsing to milliseconds changes date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, highcharts, milliseconds

I'm having trouble parsing a date from a json fetched from a server. The format of the date is "YYYY-MM-dd HH-mm-ss CST" (with the timezone at the end), this is the first entry:

```
2015-01-06 00:00:00 CST
```

I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for plotting the data, and I need to parse that into milliseconds for the a correct use in the x-axis (datetime). I'm not very familiar with date conversions in javascript, so I keep getting strange results (the parsed value in milliseconds is always wrong, therefore plotting the graph in incorrect points).

```
//obj['Time'] has the time value received = "2015-01-06 00:00:00 CST"

var fecha=obj['Time'].split(" ")[0].split("-"),
    hora=obj['Time'].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0];

var from = Date.parse( new Date(fecha[0], fecha[1], fecha[2], hora) );
```

So, I've tried the following: **1)** Parsing the obj['Time'] directly. **2)** Creating a new date object (stored in the 'from' variable) with the explicit values from the "manual splitting of the input date" and parsing that.

```
console.log("Original: " + obj['Time'] );
console.log("1) " + Date.parse(obj['Time']));
console.log("2) " + from);

console.log("Response 1: " + new Date( Date.parse(obj['Time']) ) );
console.log("Response 2: " + new Date( from ) );
```

These are the results:

```
Original: 2015-01-06 00:00:00 CST
1) 1420524000000
2) 1423177200000

Response 1: Tue Jan 06 2015 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Response 2: Fri Feb 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

**I believe** that new Date() is using my local timezone and making a conversion because the value has an offset of 1 hour (GMT+0100 ???)... So everything has an "offset" that shouldn't be there. Maybe someone can give me a heads up on what is the correct way to parse this :)

Thanks!

**Note:** I don't need to show the timezone in the charts, I just need to have the correct datetime value.

Also, I'm aware of the 0-index of the month when creating the new Date object, that's why it shows Feb instead of Jan, but it's still not correct with that fix

Comment: Date operations/manipulations (including timezones, leap years, ...)? -> Use a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Does CST mean [America/Chicago (`-06:00`) or Asia/Shanghai (`+08:00`) timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)?

Comment: Central Time Zone in America @J.F.Sebastian

Comment: I'll check it out @Andreas, the locale supports seems nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var date = "2015-01-06 00:00:00 CST".replace(/-/g, "/");
var orgDate = new Date(date);
var dateParsed = Date.parse(orgDate); //parse to timestamp. (In milliseconds)

document.write("Timestamp CST: " + dateParsed);
document.write("<br />");
document.write("<br />"); 
var dateToUTC = new Date(dateParsed);

document.write("UTC/GMT: " + dateToUTC.toUTCString());
document.write("<br />");
document.write("Local: " + dateToUTC.toString());
var timeStringUTC = Date.parse(new Date(dateToUTC.toUTCString()));
document.write("<br />"); 
document.write("<br />"); 

var UTCthen = orgDate.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+(parseInt(orgDate.getUTCMonth())+1 < 10 ? "0"+(parseInt(orgDate.getUTCMonth())+1) : orgDate.getUTCMonth()+1) + "-" + (orgDate.getUTCDate() < 10 ? "0"+orgDate.getUTCDate() : orgDate.getUTCDate())+"T00:00:00.000Z"
document.write("Timestamp UTC: " + Date.parse(UTCthen) );
document.write("<br />");   
document.write("Difference (milliseconds): " + (dateParsed - Date.parse(UTCthen)) + " // = 6 hours");  //6 hours
```

Do not parse via split. Just replace the dashes with `/`. This will make it a valid date for `Date.parse`. As you can see in the snippet. The date is sent in the *CST* time, which converted to *UTC* shows us that it's actually six in the morning in *London*. The example also shows the difference in milliseconds between both of them. I convert the parsed date back to it's original UTC timestamp. This is done in this line:

```
 var UTCthen = orgDate.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+(parseInt(orgDate.getUTCMonth())+1 < 10 ? "0"+(parseInt(orgDate.getUTCMonth())+1) : orgDate.getUTCMonth()+1) + "-" + (orgDate.getUTCDate() < 10 ? "0"+orgDate.getUTCDate() : orgDate.getUTCDate())+"T00:00:00.000Z";
```

This line gets the UTC date back and appends the time after it "T00:00:00.000Z" forcing the Date.parse to think that this is a ISO string using `Z` (Zulu) is GMT/UTC time.

So using `Date.parse` on  `UTCthen` should get you the normalized version of your timestamp.